# Specific URL for OneSignal push notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, push-notification, onesignal

I use OneSignal plugin at Wordpress to send push notifications.

Now push notifications use wordpress post's URL. How can I set specific URL for push notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To customize the URL for the notification, you can either send the notifications manually through the OneSignal dashboard, or you can customize the plugin code itself to change the behavior.

The latter option requires some PHP coding knowledge. You can find an overview of the steps required in the OneSignal documentation [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-wordpress-faq#section-onesignal_send_notification-filter).